# Last element of a for loop

Tags: for-loop

I'm splitting a document by a string delimiter in C++.

This is a minimal Python code to demonstrate the problem. la is splitted by 'x' to get (a,b,b) and (c,d) (only the element between x, or between x and end of file is recorded)

```
la = ['a','x','a','b','b','x','c','d']

out = []
tmp = []
inside = False
for a in la:
    if a == "x":
        if inside:
            out.append(tmp)
            tmp = []
        inside = True
        continue
    if inside:
        tmp.append(a)
out.append(tmp)

for a in out:
    print a
```

There is code duplication here for the last element out.append(tmp). How do I move it inside the loop?

(out.append(tmp) is actually some large code and it's prone to error to write in different places).

P/S: Since the actual code is in C++,  no special function from python is allowed to call in solving the problem

A minimal C++ code, I'm reading from a stringstream:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    stringstream instream("a x b c d x c d");
    vector<string> result;
    string word, content;
    while(getline(instream, word, ' ')) {
        if (word == "x") {
            result.push_back(content);
            content = "";
            continue;
        }
        content += word;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How those related to C++?

Comment: So this is not a Python question then? I'd expect the C++ experts here to want to see a C++ [mcve], not one coded in Python.

Comment: Why give an example in python when your problem is in C++? Why not just give what you're trying in C++ and let people help you with that code?

Comment: It's clear in the question. How do I get the same output without writing the additional code after the for loop?

Comment: So you want people to convert this python into C++, and then fix it?

Comment: What is not clear here? Let's forget about C++ part, how do I just use a for loop without additional code after that to solve the problem?

Comment: I guess it's reasonable to use Python as a form of executable pseudocode. But it appears that your potential helpers would _much_ prefer to see an MCVE  in C++.

Comment: its unclear what output you want. right now you get `['a', 'b', 'b']
['c', 'd'] ` and that seems to be ok. What is the issue with `out.append(tmp)` being outside the loop??

Comment: You just need to check if you have reached the end of the list, if so add the current a if it is not "x" and append tmp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you would not just append outside the loop but you can check the length in the loop to catch the end elements:

```
out = []
tmp = []
for ind, ele in enumerate(la):
    if ele == "x":
        if tmp:
            out.append(tmp)
        tmp = []
    elif ind == len(la) - 1:
        tmp.append(ele)
        out.append(tmp)
    else:
        tmp.append(ele)
```

You can use range in place of enumerate.

If you want to use continue you can remove the else:

```
for ind, ele in enumerate(la):
    if ele == "x":
        if tmp:
            out.append(tmp)
        tmp = []
        continue
    elif ind == len(la) - 1:
        out.append(tmp)
    tmp.append(ele)
```

I have zero experience with c++ but using stringstream.eof to catch the end of file might to do what you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    stringstream instream("x a x b c d x c d x");
    vector<string> result;
    string word, content;
    while(true) {
       getline(instream, word, ' ');
       if (instream.eof()){
          if (word != "x"){
            content += word;
          }
           cout << content << "\n";
           break;
        }
       if (word == "x") {
            result.push_back(content);
            cout << content << "\n";
            content = "";
            continue;
        }

        content += word;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a
bcd
cd
```

You also need to handle the case where he first character is `x` where you would output an empty string

Comment: It's a filestream( like a generator in Python ) so I don't know the length in advance.

Comment: Can you catch the EOF and use the same logic as the length?